# Is there a way to check if the script in background process is crashed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to write a script that checks if ffmpeg command crashed in the background. After the crash happened it should reinitialize that command. Can anyone provide a bash script code for that?

Comment: Type "jobs" to see the background jobs.

Comment: But then, you'll have to write a script that will check that the script you wrote to check if the script didn't crashed didn't crashed itself ....  ;-)

Comment: @binarym yeah that's another problem

Answer (score 0):

The following applies to any command, not just `ffmpeg`.

#### The simplest case

```bsh
: &
wait -n "$!"
echo "Status was ${?}."

false &
wait -n "$!"
echo "Status was ${?}."

(exit 17;) &
wait -n "$!"
echo "Status was ${?}."
```

#### Multiple parallel commands

```bsh
declare -i i
declare -ai pids=()

for ((i = 10; i < 20; ++i)); do
  (exit "$((i))";) &
  pids+=("$!")
done

for i in "${!pids[@]}"; do
  wait -n "${pids[i]}"
  echo "Status of command Nr. ${i}, PID ${pids[i]}, was ${?}."
done
```

#### Pipelines

```bsh
false | true | (exit 11;) | true | (exit 7;) | false

declare -i pipestatus=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")
for i in "${!pipestatus[@]}"; do
  echo "Pipeline stage ${i} terminated with status ${pipestatus[i]}."
done
```

Comment: So if my ffmpeg crashes will one of this reinitialize it again? @Andrej Podzimek

Comment: No, you have to reinitialize it once you detect a failure. So instead of a trivial command, you could run a retry loop in the background, like `for ((i = 0; i < 10; ++i)); do ffmpeg ... && break; done &`. That would retry immediately after a crash, but not indefinitely. Ultimately, when retries don’t help, the user needs to sort out the situation anyway.

Comment: I don't think that code is what I exactly want. Because I want to check the ffmpeg's situation even after it is successfully executed. But I am gonna try the others thanks for the help